# Are there animals that usually sneeze with their eyes open?

Tags: zoology

As per title. I believe that most animals tend to sneeze with their eyes closed, but wonder if any normally keep their eyes open.

Is it the case?

Comment: Maybe they can!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These marine iguanas seem to:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6G6ZL0fbLHQ

This duck does too:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZaqeRn6B7sg

Your "most animals" might just be mammals.

This turtle, however, does seem to sneeze with its eyes closed:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQTJjmfPHdE